# How can I change my code below to avoid the unexpected type error (required : variable; found: value)?

Tags: java

1.The fifth line of my code below returns an unexpected type error where a variable is required but a value found. 
2.The code is a to check if a number n is Prime or not using a while loop.

```
public boolean primeNumberCheck(int n)
{
    int divisionNumber = 2;
    boolean primeCheck = true;
    while (divisionNumber < n)
    {
        if (n%divisionNumber = 0)
        {
            primeCheck = true;
            divisionNumber = n;
        }
        else
        {
            primeCheck = false;
        }
        divisionNumber++;
    }
    return primeCheck;
}
```

Comment: change `n%divisionNumber = 0` to `n%divisionNumber == 0`

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot for that! I'll change it now.

Comment: I guess you are doing `divisionNumber = n;` to force a break out of the while loop. You could just replace that with a `break;` statement which is much clearer.

Comment: oh I didn't know you could do that with a break. Thanks for showing me that. Haven't come across that in my textbook so far so it'll really help!

Answer (score 0):

`=` is the assignment operator. `n%divisionNumber` returns a value, and you cannot assign a value to another value. So you get that error.

You need to compare the values using the `==` operator. So, you should do:

```
if (n%divisionNumber == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just realized I accidentally swapped around my true and false places.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just a more optimized algorithm based on [Primality test on WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

```
public boolean primeNumberCheck(int n) {
    // exclude numbers with divisor 2 or 3
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (n % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    // all integers can be expressed as (6k + i) for some integer k and 
    // for i = −1, 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4;
    // 2 divides (6k + 0), (6k + 2), (6k + 4); and 3 divides (6k + 3).
    // so we only have to test numbers of the form 6k +- 1
    int k = 1;
    int i = -1;
    // we only need to check candidates up to SQRT(n)
    double sqrtN = Math.Sqrt(n);
    int candidateDivisor = getCandidateDivisor(k, i);
    while (candidateDivisor < sqrtN) {        
        if (n % candidateDivisor == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        // flip i between -1 and 1
        i = -i;     
        // when i flips back to -1, increment k
        if (i < 0) {        
            k++;
        }
        candidateDivisor = getCandidateDivisor(k, i);
    }
    return true;
}

private int getCandidateDivisor(k, i) {
    return (6 * k) + i;
}
```

DISCLAIMER: I have not tested this code

Comment: I can kind of follow this along. But how does this optimize the code? What holes does it avoid compared to mine? Does it make the code run faster for larger numbers as there are less numbers to check?

Comment: It runs faster, see the Wikipedia article I referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answers here , one more tip which I follow is doing :

if (0 **==** n%divisionNumber) rather than  if (n%divisionNumber = 0).

this ensures that I haven't missed one "=" sign.